# Scrolling within a Lightbox on iPhone/iPad

Tags: drupal, scroll, mobile-safari, lightbox

I developed a [website](http://www.clawsonarchitects.com) which displays full webpages within a lightbox when certain images are clicked - the pages relate to the images. The pages are inside an IFRAME which is inside the lightbox's content div.

The problem is this: when the page inside the lightbox is longer than the height of the lightbox and the site is being viewed on iPhone/iPad, there appears to be no way to scroll the interior page - scrolling gestures scroll the outermost page (the one that the lightbox is overlaying). Mobile Safari has no scrollbars, depending entirely on gestures for scrolling, so the interior/overlayed lightbox IFRAME seems to be unscrollable.

Are there any solutions to this? Do I need to special-case mobile browsers and open a new browser window or navigate entirely to the IFRAME'd page instead of using the lightbox?

This seems to be a real shortcoming of mobile Safari!

(Not really relevant but perhaps useful info - the site is Drupal-based; the lightbox is the Lighbox2 module.)

Answer (score 0):

While not addressing the pretty serious problem of unnoticeable content on mobile safari, I would like to mention you can usually scroll this kind of content with a two-fingered scroll/swipe.

As for your case, I would do a mobile browser detect and present the user with a new browser window.

Comment: I'm afraid (sigh...) that I'll have to do the browser-detect. I HATE special-casing for browsers! FWIW, the two-finger swipe doesn't seem to work in this case anyway.